# How can i get this url part using json_decode?

Tags: php, json

I've been trying to get the "URL" part of this piece of JSON using json_decode but i can't seem to figure out how to do it.

**This is the json:**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK",
    "result": {
        "url": "https://ph2dmj.oloadcdn.net/uls/RAXxARA3DQs",
        "valid_until": "2015-10-07 19:09:01"
    }
}
```

**Here is what i've tried:**

```
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->{'url'};
```

If i replace "url" with "status" i get 200 returned so i can't understand why it won't give me the url when i enter URL?

Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($obj)`. and you'll see exactly what path to take. tip: `$obj->result->more stuff`. and another tip: ignore the fact that you have json. once you decode, it's a plain regular PHP data structure. json is just the wrapping paper it came in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access url through result like this: 
`$obj->result->url`

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize i had to do that.